# How to install Nokogiri using gcc on MacOS Catalina

Tags: ruby, gcc, nokogiri

I am trying to install Nokogiri on my MacOS Catalina 10.15.1 system.

```
gem install nokogiri
```

The error in the log file is:

```
"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/shairyar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0/x86_64-darwin18 -I/Users/shairyar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/shairyar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/include/ruby-2.6.0 -I. -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe  -I /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/shairyar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L. -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib     -lruby.2.6    "
    gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wdivision-by-zero'; did you mean '-Wdiv-by-zero'?
    gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wshorten-64-to-32'
    gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wextra-tokens'; did you mean '-Wextra-semi'?
    checked program was:
    /* begin */
    1: #include "ruby.h"
    2:
    3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
    4: {
    5:   return 0;
    6: }
    /* end */
```

I have been searching and tried installing gcc using `brew install gcc` and `brew link gcc` but that does not help.

Here is the gcc version I have:

```
$which gcc
/usr/local/bin/gcc

$gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin19/9.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19
Configured with: ../gcc-9.2.0/configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin19 --disable-nls --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --disable-multilib --with-sysroot=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --with-gmp=/usr/local --with-mpc=/usr/local --with-mpfr=/usr/local
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.2.0 (GCC)
```

I also tried the following which did not work:

1. `gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries`
2. `CC=llvm-gcc gem install nokogiri`

Comment: Have you tried these? https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1257

Comment: @Casper yes i have `CC=llvm-gcc gem install nokogiri` did not work and since i do not have `apple-gcc42` so i did not need to uninstall it

Comment: What if you uninstall gcc completely? If no tricks are working, then perhaps open an issue on the nokogiri repo. You could of course also try to fix it yourself if you're not afraid of a bit of tinkering (git clone the repo, and fix the command line switches, or figure out why it sets them incorrectly for gcc on Catalina).

Comment: Thanks @Casper for the tip

Comment: Have you installed [XCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)? Its command-line tools are what gem always uses when I install anything with native code.

Comment: @theTinMan yes i have Xcode installed

Comment: I ended up fixing this my removing the gcc completely and it worked. thanks @Casper

Comment: That's great. Nice. You can answer your own question and approve it, so others can see it too.

Comment: Yes, just added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem I deleted the gcc I installed, located at `/usr/local/bin/gcc`, and that seems to have solved my problem. When I ran the command

```
which gcc
```

the output I got was:

```
/usr/local/bin/gcc
```

I needed the one that Apple installed located at `/usr/bin/gcc`.